# Java Buffered Reader Text File Parsing

Tags: java, text-parsing

I am really struggling with parsing a text file. I have a text file which is in the following format

```
ID
Float Float 
Float Float
....   // variable number of floats
END
ID
Float Float 
Float Float
....   
END
```

etc However the ID can represent one of two values, 0 which means it is a new field, or -1 which means it is related to the last new field. The number of times a related field can repeat it self is unlimited. Which is where the problem is occurring.

As I have a method in a library which takes an ArrayList of the new Floats, then an ArrayList of an ArrayList of the related floats.

When I try and code the logic for this I just keep getting deeper and deeper embedded while loops.

I would really appreciate any suggestions as to how I should go about this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(buildingsFile));

        String[] line = br.readLine().trim().split("    ");
        boolean original = true;

        while(true)
        {
            if(line[0].equals("END"))
                break;

            startCoordinate = new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(line[0]), Double.parseDouble(line[1]));

            while(true)
            {
                line = br.readLine().trim().split("    ");

                if(!line[0].equals("END") && original == true)
                    polypoints.add(new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(line[0]), Double.parseDouble(line[1])));
                else if(!line[0].equals("END") && original == false)
                    cutout.add(new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(line[0]), Double.parseDouble(line[1])));
                else if(line[0].equals("END") && original == false)
                {
                    cutouts.add(cutout);
                    cutout.clear();
                }
                else if(line[0].equals("-99999"))
                    original = false;
                else if(line[0].equals("0"))
                    break;
            }

            buildingDB.addBuilding(mapName, startCoord, polypoints, cutouts);
        }
```

New Code

```
        int i = 0;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(buildingsFile));

        String[] line;

        while(true)
        {
            line = br.readLine().trim().split("    ");

            if(line[0].equals("END"))
                break;

            polygons.add(new Polygon(line));

            while(true)
            {
                line = br.readLine().trim().split("    ");

                if(line[0].equals("END"))
                    break;
                polygons.get(i).addCoord(new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(line[0]), Double.parseDouble(line[1])));
            }



            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(polygons.size());


        int j = 0;
        for(i = 0; i< polygons.size(); i++)
        {
            Building newBuilding = new Building();

            if(polygons.get(i).isNew == true)
            {
                newBuilding = new Building();
                newBuilding.startCoord = new Coordinate(polygons.get(i).x, polygons.get(i).y);
            }

            while(polygons.get(i).isNew == false)
                newBuilding.cutouts.add(polygons.get(i).coords);

            buildings.add(newBuilding);
        }

        for(i = 0; i<buildings.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            buildingDB.addBuilding(mapName, buildings.get(i).startCoord, buildings.get(i).polypoint, buildings.get(i).cutouts);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post what you're currently doing (your code) so we can make suggestions based on your current strategy rather than cover the same ground that you've already done?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a "field" means an ID and a variable number of coordinates (pairs of floats), that, judging from your code, represents a polygon in fact.

I would first load all the polygons, each into a separate `Polygon` object:

```
class Polygon {
    boolean isNew;
    List<Coordinate> coordinates;
}
```

and store the polygons in another list. Then in a 2nd pass go through all the polygons to group them according to their IDs into something like

```
class Building {
    Polygon polygon;
    List<Polygon> cutouts;
}
```

I think this would be fairly simple to code.

OTOH if you have a huge amount of data in the file, and/or you prefer processing the read data little by little, you could simply read a polygon and all its associated cutouts, until you find the next polygon (ID of 0), at which point you could simply pass the stuff read so far to the building DB and start reading the next polygon.

Comment: Thanks ill try the first method you suggested, i have adapted the one i posted but it has taken 10 minutes to get to the 35th building and seems to have stopped there.

Comment: I have implemented this, however java is now reporting that I have run out of space on the heap which is rather unusual, any ideas?

Comment: @John-- hmmmm. How big is the file you are trying to read? Approx. how many polygons there are in it? Could you post your updated code?

Comment: There are 135 polygons in the file, some having over 50 points. Ill upload my current code now.

Comment: @John-- You don't seem to initialize Polygon.isNew anywhere. And this while loop never terminates:  

    while(polygons.get(i).isNew == false)
        newBuilding.cutouts.add(polygons.get(i).coords);

Comment: in the polygon class I set them to be false by default, and the constructor tests the first line to see if it is a cutout setting it to true. The first two while loops which get the list of polygons works rather quickly, its just when adding them to the buildings/adding to the database that I get the memory problems.

Comment: Thanks hadnt noticed the infinite while loop() just getting a few null pointer exceptions now which should be easy enough to remove

Comment: Great, you are progressing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use map for new floats and related floats..if got your question it should help..example:

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("Rohit", new Double(3434.34));
```

Comment: u would use floats in map..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ANTLR here, The Grammar defines the format of the text you are expecting and then you can wrap the contents in a Java object. The * and + Wildcards will resolve the complexity of while and for. Its very simple and easy to use, you dont have to construct AST you can take the parsed content from java objects directly. But the only overhead is you have to add the ANTLR.jar to your path.